# Couldn't load plugin 'processing' on starting QGIS3 on a mac

Tags: qgis-processing, qgis-3

I'm getting an error message when I start QGIS3. I've tried all sorts but don't know what else to do?

```
 Couldn't load plugin 'processing' 

ImportError: cannot import name 'ogr' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 312, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/__init__.py", line 28, in 
    from processing.tools.dataobjects import *          # NOQA
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/dataobjects.py", line 51, in 
    from processing.algs.gdal.GdalUtils import GdalUtils
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/GdalUtils.py", line 38, in 
    from osgeo import ogr
ImportError: cannot import name 'ogr'


Python version: 3.6.5 (default, Apr 25 2018, 14:22:56) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] 
QGIS version: 3.2.1-Bonn Bonn, exported 

Python Path:
/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python
/Users/Lauh/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/Lauh/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/Users/Lauh/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
```